# How will svnsync handle commits on a branch of the mirror repository?

Tags: svn, svnsync

I have the following svn repository setup:

- repo A: Master repo
- repo B: Mirror-repo of repo A (mirrored using [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnsync.html))

There are two different kinds of developers:

- Developer1: commits only on trunk and release branches of repo A
- Developer2: commits only to a dedicated branch of repo B

Since I have not used svnsync before: how will svnsync handle a commit done by Developer2 to the dedicated branch in repo B?

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication) says you should not ever commit to mirror repository other way than via *svnsync*:

The protocol that svnsync uses to communicate revision information is highly sensitive to mismatches between the versioned histories contained in the source and target repositories. For this reason, while svnsync cannot demand that the target repository be read-only, allowing the revision history in the target repository to change by any mechanism other than the mirroring process is a **recipe for disaster**.

Do not modify a mirror repository in such a way as to cause its version history to deviate from that of the repository it mirrors. **The only commits and revision property modifications that ever occur on that mirror repository should be those performed by the svnsync tool.**

Comment: So in this case, it is probably less pain to somehow allow Developer2 to access repo A directly and work on a dedicated branch there.

Comment: @ptikobj Seems so. Sounds better than adding another repo C.